# Different Output in matrix Multiplication Python vs Swift

Tags: python, swift, matrix, multiplication

I'm writing a code of matrix multiplication in swift and python but both code generate a different output. 
I also write this code in C++ but it generate same output as in python, I checked swift code again and again but I got no difference
I'm trying to multiply these two matrix

#### Matrix A

```
1 0 1
0 0 0
1 0 1
```

#### Matrix B

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 0
0 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
0 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 5 0
0 4 5 6 7 8 9 3 4 0
0 4 5 6 7 8 9 2 3 0
0 5 6 7 8 9 0 4 6 0
0 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 8 0
0 7 8 9 1 2 3 0 5 0
0 8 9 2 4 5 6 4 8 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

### Here's my Python Code

```
row,col = 8,9 
result = [[0 for x in range(row)] for y in range(col)]
row,col=0,0
for matrixB_Row in range(0,9):
    for matrixB_Col in range(0,8):
        for matrixA_Row in range(0,3):
            for i in range(0,3):
                for matrixA_Col in range(0,3):
                    result[row][col] = result[row][col]+(matrixA[matrixA_Row][matrixA_Col]*matrixA[matrixB_Row][matrixB_Col])
                    matrixA_Col+=1
                    matrixB_Row+=1
                i+=1
                matrixB_Col+=1
                matrixB_Row = matrixB_Row-3
            matrixB_Col = matrixB_Col-3
            matrixA_Row+=1
        col+=1
        matrixB_Col+=1
    row+=1
    col=0
    matrixB_Row=+1
    matrixB_Col=0
```

### Here's my swift code

```
var Row = 0, Col = 0, MatrixB_Col = 0, MatrixB_Row = 0, MatrixA_Col = 0, MatrixA_Row = 0, i = 0
        var result = [[Int]](repeating: [Int](repeating: 0, count: 8), count: 9)
        while MatrixB_Row < 9
        {
            MatrixB_Col = 0
            while MatrixB_Col < 8{
                MatrixA_Row = 0
                while MatrixA_Row < 3 {
                    i = 0
                    while i < 3 {
                        MatrixA_Col = 0
                        while MatrixA_Col < 3{
                            result[Row][Col] += (matrixA[MatrixA_Row][MatrixA_Col] * matrixB[MatrixB_Row][MatrixB_Col]);
                            MatrixA_Col+=1
                            MatrixB_Row+=1
                        }
                        i+=1
                        MatrixB_Col+=1
                        MatrixB_Row = MatrixB_Row - 3
                    }
                    MatrixA_Row+=1
                    MatrixB_Col = MatrixB_Col - 3
                }
                MatrixB_Col+=1
                Col+=1
            }
            Row+=1
            Col=0
            MatrixB_Row+=1
            MatrixB_Col = 0
        }
```

Comment: Is it even possible to multiply these two matrices? I thought you can only multiply two matrices A and B if number of columns of A equals the number of rows in B>

Comment: I'm multiplying by picking first 3 row and 3 column multiply it then add it and then put it into result[0][0] after that, I am picking next 3 row and column and apply the same method till the end

Comment: That's convolution, it involves matrix multiplication, but it isn't matrix multiplication

Comment: @Alexander yes, it's convolution but here's issue with that

Answer (score 3):

Multiplication in your python code:

```
result[row][col] = result[row][col]+(matrixA[matrixA_Row][matrixA_Col]*matrixA[matrixB_Row][matrixB_Col])
```

Here you're using elements only from matrix A for multiplication.

Multiplication in your swift code:

```
result[Row][Col] += (matrixA[MatrixA_Row][MatrixA_Col] * matrixB[MatrixB_Row][MatrixB_Col]);
```

Here you're using both matrix A and matrix B.
That's why the results are different - you have an error in your python code.

Comment: `an error in your python code` non-trivial to spot through a stackexchange code keyhole for exceeding [PEP8 maximum line length](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) by miles.

Answer (score 0):

Can you run the numbers through this and compare?

https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-algorithm-club/tree/master/Strassen%20Matrix%20Multiplication